# Trying to pivot max date into column along with the status of the case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on dataset where each case contains multiple rows with the status that it went through, I am trying to pivot the `max(time_stamp)` of my `final_decision_time` and the `final_status` of case by the Group.

I am trying something like this and I'm stuck at transposing row into column with the status

```
Select [ro #],WCC_Approv_Decis,CSE_Approv_Decis,RSM_Approv_Decis,FSD_Approv_Decis,max(case when WCC_Approv_Decis in ('Rejected','Approved')  Then  WCC_Approv_Decis_Date end) over (partition by [ro #]) as WCC_Approve_Date,

 max(case when CSE_Approv_Decis in ('Rejected','Approved')  Then  CSE_Approv_Decis_Date end) over (partition by [ro #]) as CSE_Approve_Date,
 max(case when RSM_Approv_Decis in ('Rejected','Approved')  Then  RSM_Approv_Decis_Date end) over (partition by [ro #]) as RSM_Approve_Date,
 max(case when FSD_Approv_Decis in ('Rejected','Approved')  Then  FSD_Approv_Decis_Date end) over (partition by [ro #]) as FSD_Approve_Date
 from #FinalResultset where [ro #] in ('397142')
```

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|   Case    | WCF_Approv_Decis | WCF_Approv_Decis_Date | CSA_Approv_Decis | CSA_Approv_Decis_Date | RSA_Approv_Decis | RSA_Approv_Decis_Date | FSB_Approv_Decis | FSB_Approv_Decis_Date |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|    386646 |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 3/3/2020 15:24        |                  | NULL                  |
|    386646 |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 2/27/2020 16:37       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |
|    386646 | Rejected         | 2/19/2020 17:30       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |
|    397142 |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 5/29/2020 18:58       |                  | NULL                  |
|    397142 |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 5/29/2020 18:34       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |
|    397142 | Rejected         | 5/29/2020 13:40       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

I am trying to get an extra columns with the final_decision_date with status of the case like below

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+
|   Case    | WCF_Approv_Decis | WCF_Approv_Decis_Date | CSA_Approv_Decis | CSA_Approv_Decis_Date | RSA_Approv_Decis | RSA_Approv_Decis_Date | FSB_Approv_Decis | FSB_Approv_Decis_Date | Fina_Decision | Final_Decision_Date |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+
|    386646 |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 3/3/2020 15:24        |                  | NULL                  | Approved      | 3/3/2020 15:24      |
|    386646 |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 2/27/2020 16:37       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved      | 3/3/2020 15:24      |
|    386646 | Rejected         | 2/19/2020 17:30       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved      | 3/3/2020 15:24      |
|    397142 |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 5/29/2020 18:58       |                  | NULL                  | Approved      | 5/29/2020 18:58     |
|    397142 |                  | NULL                  | Approved         | 5/29/2020 18:34       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved      | 5/29/2020 18:58     |
|    397142 | Rejected         | 5/29/2020 13:40       |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  |                  | NULL                  | Approved      | 5/29/2020 18:58     |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: How are you arriving at final decision. It is not clear. You have got different approval decision columns

Comment: @DaleK ..,I am trying something like this

Answer (score 0):

There may be CTE help, I assume that if there no decision XXX_Decis is empty string and XXX_Decis_Date is NULL, and only one of this is filled:

```
WITH Decisions AS (
  SELECT
    [Case],
    COALESCE (WCF_Approv_Decis_Date, CSA_Approv_Decis_Date, RSA_Approv_Decis_Date, FSB_Approv_Decis_Date) AS Approv_Decis_Date,
    CONCAT(WCF_Approv_Decis, CSA_Approv_Decis, RSA_Approv_Decis, FSB_Approv_Decis ) AS Approv_Decis
  FROM XXX
), FinalDecisions AS (
  SELECT 
    [Case],
    Approv_Decis AS Final_Decision,
    Approv_Decis_Date AS Final_Decision_Date
  FROM Decisions
  WHERE Approv_Decis_Date = MAX(Approv_Decis_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY [Case])
)

SELECT 
  XXX.Case, 
  WCF_Approv_Decis, 
  WCF_Approv_Decis_Date, 
  CSA_Approv_Decis, 
  CSA_Approv_Decis_Date, 
  RSA_Approv_Decis, 
  RSA_Approv_Decis_Date, 
  FSB_Approv_Decis, 
  FSB_Approv_Decis_Date, 
  Final_Decision, 
  Final_Decision_Date
FROM XXX
LEFT JOIN FinalDecisions 
  ON XXX.Case = FinalDecisions.Case
```

Comment: Thanks @Leszek Mazur .., RSA_Approv_Decis may not be  the final status of case. There is  a chance case can reviewed by multiple groups and sometimes not.

Comment: So can you provide rules?

Comment: If the case not reviewed by any group the logic should check the previous group status and time_stamp of previous group